# Is "too, once" or "once, too" correct?

Tags: commas, word-order, sentence-ends

Is "too, once" or "once, too" correct?
Or can we just simply choose one of those 2 words?
Do we need to use comma?

Here's the sentence:

> "You did it to me (too, once) / (once, too)."

Thanks!

Comment: If you must use such a sentence I certainly prefer the former to the latter.

Comment: @WS2: I think it's entirely a matter of stylistic choice. But in actual fact, Google Books claims 6230 hits for "the latter" [*to him once too*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22to+him+once+too%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), compared to just 5 for [*to him too once*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22to+him+too+once%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). And I can't see any reason to suppose a change of pronoun would make that much difference to such a marked preference. (By implication, nin, you can happily use either! :)

Comment: though I'm a bit perturbed to see on checking that *four* of those five results are just "accidental collocations" :)

Comment: My first implication was to VTC as "matter of opinion", but that Google Books preference seems *very* strange. I'm now intrigued enough to *upvote* the question!

Answer (score 1):

***Brilliant sentence:***

> .1. Once, you did it to me too.

means you used to, but not any longer.

> .2. You once did it to me too.

means on one occasion, I remember you did that to me as well; or
you used to include me.

> .3. You did  it once to me, too.

means on one occasion you did that to me as well.

> *4. You did it to me once, too. X

This is infelicitous. There is a partial verbal ambiguity from the juxtaposition of Once with too/two. I.e. this is a 'garden path' phrase where the two/too homonym is distracting.

> .5. You did it to me too, once.

Like 2 this means either once upon a time you did this to me; or on one occasion you even/ also did this to me.

To include both ideas choose two or five.  For precision, choose one or three.

Answer (score -1):

Both sound rather awkward and might require rephrasing, like "you once did it to me as well", or "you once did it to me too". The practice of inserting a comma to break up the rhythm of a sentence like you have here is often one taken from speech, not writing. Using a comma in this instance is merely preferential.